# Kohana 3 - How should I handle urls within views

Tags: url, hyperlink, kohana, uri, kohana-3

I'm running Kohana 3 (latest) and I don't know how to handle links in my views. For example. My base url is http://localhost/foo/. I have a menu like and this menu is shared between bar and baz page:

```
<a href="bar">Bar</a>
<a href="baz">Baz</a>
```

If i'm in my home page, my links are:

```
http://localhost/foo/bar
http://localhost/foo/baz.
```

These links are in the same. If i click into bar link, for example the my links will be something like:

```
http://localhost/foo/bar/bar
http://localhost/foo/bar/baz.
```

What's wrong? How should i handle urls?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to use:

```
URL::site('bar');
```

This will make a relative URL, including the base_path and index.php (if it's enabled, ofc).

You can also use `Route::url()` to produce the same thing using a route.

```
Route::url('route_name', array('id' => $id));
```

This doesn't concern views only but all sitelinks.

Comment: But should I use it directly in the view? Thanks

Comment: If you're not using a view model (Musache/Kostache) then yes, it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use Kohana's [Html::anchor()](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/HTML#anchor) method:

```
echo HTML::anchor('bar', 'Bar');
```

Comment: Yep! Its ok if you are using HTML or FORM helpers in your views.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just include `<base>` tag in your `<head>`, something like this:

```
<head>
  ...
  <base href="<?php echo url::base(); ?>" />
  ...
</head>
```

With this inside your view, every link you use will be relative to `<base>` not to the current address. This way `<a href="bar">Bar</a>` will always be pointing to `http://localhost/foo/bar` no matter on which page you use it.